# implementing interface in android linear layout class android

Tags: android, interface, android-linearlayout

I am developing small android application in which i created one class abc which extends LinearLayout and one activity xyz. Inside my class abc i define one interface in following manner

```
public class abc extends LinearLayout {


    private OnclickxitemListener listener1;

    public interface OnclickxitemListener
    {
        public String nil = "nilkash";
        public void onclickxtitem();
    }

    public void setOnxitemSelectedListener(OnclickxitemListener listener) 
    { 
        this.listener1 = listener;  
        Log.i("#######################################", "inside set listener "+listener1);
    } 

    public abc(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void initialiseImages()
    {

        create custome linear view here
        ImageView image_View = (ImageView) parentLayout.findViewById(0);
        image_View.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        { 
            String n = listener1.nil;
            Log.i("#################################", "inside click"+n);
            listener1.onclickxitem(); 
        }
        });
    }

}
```

Now I tred to use this interface from my activity in following manner.

```
public class xyz extends Activity implements abc.OnclickxitemListener{

    CustomviewActivity cubes;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    abc widget = new abc(this); 
    widget.setOnxitemSelectedListener(this);

        cubes.initialiseImages();
    }


    @Override
    public void onclickxitem() {

    }

}
```

Now problem is that when I excuted image click listener in my class I am able to access variable value ("string nilkash") but I am not able to access method `listener1.onclickxitem();`. when i tried to acees that it gives me null pointer exception.

Whether I am doing anything wrong. How to solve this problem.
need help...
Thank you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I am really a little confused with your code. I would do something like this. If abc is my custom view in package com.test in my activity layout file xyz.xml

```
<com.test.abc
android:id="@+id/myview"
<!-- You can modify the values below the way you want -->
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="300dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

In my abc class i would write something like this

```
public class abc extends ImageView{

  private OnclickxitemListener listener;

    public interface OnclickxitemListener
    {
      public String nil = "nilkash";
      public void onclickxtitem();
    }


    public void setOnxitemSelectedListener(OnclickxitemListener l )
    {
      listener = l;

    }

     public abc(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
      super(context, attrs);
      initialize();

    }

    public void initialize()
    {

      this.setImageResource(R.drawable.*name of the image saved in drawable*);


        setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

         @Override
     public void onClick(View arg0) 
         {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    notifyListener();
         }

        });
     }

     private void notifyListener()
     {
            if (null!=listener)
            listener.onclickxtitem();
     }
}
```

Finally in your activity xyz

```
public class xyz extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.xyz);

        abc myview = (abc)findViewById(R.id.myview);
        myview.setOnxitemSelectedListener(new abc.OnclickxitemListener()
             {
                @Override
                public void onclickxtitem()
                 {


                 }
              });

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you pasted in, your activity needs to implement OnclickxitemListener for your abc class to callback on. Remove the onclickxitem from your activity, implement the OnclickxitemListener and let your IDE implement the unimplemented onclickxitem method from the interface.

Calling cubes.initialiseImages(); will also give you a null pointer as cubes has not been initialised. Surely you want to be calling widget.initialiseImages()?

You are able to access the listener1.nil String as this has been declared and given a value.

Comment: hye hi domji thank you for reply.... So according to you r opinion I have to implement OnclickxitemListener for abc class and my xyz activity as well right? And second thing is that I need initialiseImages() method becoz i need to pass some params like image array. so thats why I am using that... Can you plz explain your ans more so that I can try it... Thank you for your help

Comment: You are declaring the OnclickxitemListener in your abc class. To implement this in your xyz Activity, your declaration should look like this public "class xyz extends Activity implements OnclickxitemListener". Also you are not adding your view to the xyz layout so I don't know how your abc widget will ever show in your xyz Activity. If you upload your project and post a link here, I could fix it for you, upload it and send you a link back.

Comment: hi Domji thank you for reply.. i got you what you want to say. I implemented my clickListener as you said.And about your second question that how can my widget will displayed into xyz activity. I included that into my xyz layout file i.e. main.xml. So it display my layout into my activity.I solve my problem according to GIZ's solution(above). Thank you for your ultimate help... Thankx a lot.. If you have any conceptual guideline regarding custom layouts then plz share with us so that we also come to know about it..